# How to read a private Google Spreadsheet that is located in a private shared drive in R?

Tags: r, google-sheets, data-science, private

I am trying to write a script in R that reads a Google Spreadsheet that is only accessible for people who it is shared with. The Spreadsheet is also in a Shared Drive (only accessible for people who it is shared with). I am aware of the googlespreadsheets package but do not know how to handle reading in a private spreadsheet.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2):

In a situation where the Google Sheet is changing frequently, accessing up to date contents directly from Google is preferable to manually extracting a CSV file.

We can use the `googlesheets4` package to access Google Sheets spreadsheets that require authentication.

For example, I'll read a spreadsheet of Pokémon Stats that is stored on Google. We'll authenticate our session with the `gs4_auth()` function, obtain a list of spreadheets so we can access them by `id`, and then read the Pokémon Stats spreadsheet's first worksheet.

```
library(googlesheets4)
# change next line to google account you need to access
# Respond to message in R console, then a browser window
# will open for you to complete the authentication process
gs4_auth(email = "yourGoogleAccount@gmail.com")
theSheets <-gs4_find()
```

At this point one can print the `theSheets` to find the sheet to download.

```
> theSheets
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  name         id                                           drive_resource   
* <chr>        <chr>                                        <list>           
1 PokemonStats <------------redacted----------------------> <named list [34]>
```

Now we can use the `theSheets$id` to access the spreadsheet via the `sheets_read()` function.

```
pokemonData <- sheets_read(theSheets$id[1],sheet = 1)
head(pokemonData)
```

...and the output:

```
> pokemonData <- sheets_read(theSheets$id[1],sheet = 1)
Reading from "PokemonStats"
Range "'Pokemon'"
> head(pokemonData)
# A tibble: 6 x 13
  Number Name                  Type1 Type2  Total    HP Attack Defense SpecialAtk SpecialDef Speed Generation Legendary
   <dbl> <chr>                 <chr> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl> <lgl>    
1      1 Bulbasaur             Grass Poison   318    45     49      49         65         65    45          1 FALSE    
2      2 Ivysaur               Grass Poison   405    60     62      63         80         80    60          1 FALSE    
3      3 Venusaur              Grass Poison   525    80     82      83        100        100    80          1 FALSE    
4      3 VenusaurMega Venusaur Grass Poison   625    80    100     123        122        120    80          1 FALSE    
5      4 Charmander            Fire  NA       309    39     52      43         60         50    65          1 FALSE    
6      5 Charmeleon            Fire  NA       405    58     64      58         80         65    80          1 FALSE
```

### Shared Google Sheets

To validate that sheets shared with my account are accessible via `gs4_find()`, I created a sheet called `TestSpreadsheet` and shared it with the Google account used for this answer.

```
> theSheets <-gs4_find()
> theSheets
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  name            id                                           drive_resource   
* <chr>           <chr>                                        <list>           
1 TestSpreadsheet <------------redacted----------------------> <named list [34]>
2 PokemonStats    <------------redacted----------------------> <named list [34]>
```

To read the sheet, we access it by `id`.

```
theId <- theSheets$id[theSheets$name == "TestSpreadsheet"]
testData <- sheets_read(theId,sheet = 1)
testData
```

...and the output:

```
> testData <- sheets_read(theId,sheet = 1)
Reading from "TestSpreadsheet"
Range "'Sheet1'"
> testData
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   `Column 1` `Column 2`
        <dbl>      <dbl>
 1          1         20
 2          2         30
 3          3         40
 4          4         50
 5          5         60
 6          6         70
 7          7         80
 8          8         90
 9          9        100
10         10        110
>
```

Answer (score 0):

In google sheet :

1. At top Click "File" : Publish to web
2. Publishing Option: Choose "csv" file
3. Click Publish
4. Copy the URL

And try the Code below:

```
library(RCurl)

url <- getURL("URL You Copied")

file <- textConnection(url)

data <- read.csv(file)
```